# getting internal Server error and empty Object

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

made an API for Social media Application  to get timeline posts on the app, I requested from Thunder Client
request query is like: **http://localhost:8000/post/63d4051a252ef6c3d50d7f17/timeline**, where **userId** is this :63d4051a252ef6c3d50d7f17,

i did log **userId**  and correctly got Data Document from  **mongoDB**

```
try {
    const currentUserPost = await PostModel.find({ userId: userId });
    console.log( currentUserPost )
}
```

but still getting empty object {}  **error is: Internal server error status code 500** on thunder client,

check out once below code, and let me know what's wrong and why. it seems good to me but it isn't working.

**PostControler.js**

```
const PostModel = require("../Models/Postmodels");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const UserModel = require("../Models/Usermodel");
/ get timeLine post

const getTimeLinePost = async (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.params.id;
  
  try {
    const currentUserPost = await PostModel.find({ userId: userId });

    console.log( currentUserPost )

    const followingPost = await UserModel.aggregate([
      
      {
        $match: {
          _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId),
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "posts",
          localField: "following",
          foreignField: "userId",
          as: "followingPosts",
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          followingPost: 1,
          _id: 0,
        }
      },
    ]);

   
    res.status(200).json(currentUserPost.concat(...followingPost[0].followingPost)
.sort((a,b)=>{
        return b.createdAt - a.createdAt 
      }));
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
};



module.exports = { createPost,getPost, updatePost, deletePost, likesDislikesPost, getTimeLinePost  };
```

**PostRoute.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const {createPost,getPost, updatePost, deletePost, likesDislikesPost, getTimeLinePost} = require("../Controller/PostControler");


const router = express.Router();


router.post('/', createPost)
router.get('/:id', getPost)
router.put('/:id', updatePost)
router.delete('/:id', deletePost)
router.put('/:id/like', likesDislikesPost)
router.get('/:id/timeline', getTimeLinePost)




module.exports = router
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express")
require('dotenv').config()
const bodyparser = require("body-parser")
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const app = express();
const Authroute = require("./Routes/Authroute")
const UserRoute = require("./Routes/userRout")

const PostRout = require("./Routes/PostRoute")

.
.
.
.
.
.




app.use("/auth",Authroute)
app.use("/user",UserRoute)
app.use("/post", PostRout)
```

Comment: In catch block, Please add `console.log(error)` before `res.status(500).send(error);` and probably you will get your answer in the terminal/cmd or may provide error here to get help by community

Comment: okay let me try this

Comment: Can you post `UserModel` schema declaration?

Comment: I got this error:  **TypeError: followingPost[0].followingPost is not iterable (cannot read property undefined)**

Comment: and if I do like this ** res.status(200).json(currentUserPost.concat(followingPost))**  in response return single document instead of all followers , its means not **concat**  both data ** curentUserPost and followingPost**